# i don't know why it appears this mistake

Tags: c

I made a code for printing a matrix in c:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int i,j,columna,n,m;
    char sala_cine[X][Y];

    sala_cine[X][Y]=
    {
        {' ',1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20},
        {'1',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
        {'2',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
        {'3',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
        {'4',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
        {'5',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
        {'6',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
        {'7',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
        {'8',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '}
    };
    for (i=0;i<X;i++){
        for(j=0;j<Y;j++)
            printf("%c",sala_cine[X][Y]);
    printf("\n");
    }

return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

and in the row of  `sala_cine[X][Y]=` it appear this mistake:

```
expeted expression before '{' token.
```

Can you help me to solve the problem?

Thank you

Comment: You want to print `sala_cine[i][j]`, not `sala_cine[X][Y]`. And I hope you have your `X,Y` defined.

Comment: You are mixing `char` and `int` values: `'1'` is a character showing a one, `1` is a special character not the character one.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot assign an array in C like this. But in your case you can initialize at declaration :

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int i,j,columna,n,m;
    char sala_cine[X][Y] =
    {
        {' ',1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20},
        {'1',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
        {'2',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
        {'3',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
        {'4',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
        {'5',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
        {'6',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
        {'7',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
        {'8',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '}
    };
    for (i=0;i<X;i++){
        for(j=0;j<Y;j++)
            printf("%c",sala_cine[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Also, the for loop that prints had a bug as @Eugene pointed out

Answer (score 0):

With C11, code can assign a compound literal to `sala_cine`, which is now a pointer.

```
  sala_cine = (char [X][Y]) { ... } // see below
```

Note: that printing `(char)` will print a control character and not the digit `'1'`.

```
#define X 9
#define Y 21

int main(void) {
    int i,j;
    char (*sala_cine)[Y];
    sala_cine = (char [X][Y])
    {
        {' ',1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20},
        {'1',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
        {'2',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
        {'3',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
        {'4',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
        {'5',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
        {'6',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
        {'7',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
        {'8',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '}
    };
    for (i=0;i<X;i++){
        for(j=0;j<Y;j++)
            // printf("%c",sala_cine[X][Y]);
            // Change from X,Y to i,j;
            printf("%c",sala_cine[i][j]);
    printf("\n");
    }

return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C, you cannot declare an array in one step, and initialize it later. (as you tried to do):

```
// WRONG
char sala_cine[X][Y];          // Declaration Step
sala_cine[X][Y]=    {  .... }; // Initialization Step
```

Instead, you must do it at once:

```
// Correct
char sala_cine[X][Y] = { .....};          // Declaration and Initialization at once.
```